# Codename One - upload pictures to Filestack

Tags: codenameone

I want to upload pictures to Filestack (former Filepicker.io) using my CN1 app. I am using their REST API to do so. I am using the MultipartRequest class and after I run the app, I can see on their website that something is being uploaded, because the size of the file has the same size of the taken picture, but I can't see the picture.

Is there something missing in my code?

```
public void pictureUpload() {
    String picture = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);
    if(picture!=null){
        String filestack = "https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MY_KEY&filename=myPicture.jpg";
        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
        request.setUrl(filestack);
        resquest.setPost(true);
        request.setHttpMethod("POST");
        try {
            request.addData("i", picture, "image/jpeg");
            request.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
        } catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this from their website:

```
curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@ada.jpg https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=Am3XXBhQ4SxiEQU7cLfM5z
{"url": "https://www.filestackapi.com/api/file/cTy7LpA6SfyG26Wzz7Rx", "size": 124928, "type": "image/jpg", "filename": "filename"}
```

It looks like the file name shouldn't be in the arguments above:

```
public void pictureUpload(final Callback<String> resultURL) {
    String picture = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);
    if(picture!=null){
        String filestack = "https://www.filestackapi.com/api/store/S3?key=MY_KEY&filename=myPicture.jpg";
        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest() {
           protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException  {
              JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
              Map<String, Object> result = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
              String url = (String)result.get("url");
              if(url == null) {
                 resultURL.onError(null, null, 1, result.toString());
                 return;
              }
              resultURL.onSucess(url);
           }
        };
        request.setUrl(filestack);
        try {
            request.addData("fileUpload", picture, "image/jpeg");
            request.setFilename("fileUpload", "myPicture.jpg");
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
        } catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also removed the `setPost` and post method which are unnecessary as those are the defaults.

Also added some JSON result parsing for good measure and some callback URL results since this looks like a good example for the multipart class.

So I've made a GIST of the answer to embed in the javadocs.

Comment: what is the purpose of the Callback argument? And where should it come from when implementing the method? (1000 thanks for the above answer)

Comment: The callback is for convenience to make the method complete. Your code didn't read the result from the webservice which is a JSON file containing a link to the uploaded file. I parsed it and sent back the URL for the resulting file (notice I didn't test this so if there is a bug please let me know). The resulting file link is probably important for your app. Notice that the Callback interface is builtin to Codename One.